# Error on upload of Opera extension to addon store

Tags: opera-extension

When I login and upload either a new Opera addon or attempt to upgrade an existing one, I get the following error from the Opera addon control panel: "Upload error has occured: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR".

To prepare the addon for upload, I am using the 'Pack Extension' option from the addons page in the Opera browser, then attempting to upload the generated .nex file.

Comment: Can you provide your user name or email you use to log-in to the Opera add-ons portal? If you don't want to share it here, just use https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/desktop to report it.

Comment: Thanks Łukasz. I've created a bug at the URL you mention and received the following identifier: DNAWIZ-12944-at-bugs.opera.com

Comment: Also, I wanted to let another dev try the upload, however I can't find any link  on the site to add another person for addon admin?

Comment: Hi. For adding a new person as an extension's admin you need to contact moderators via the developer panel.

Comment: For anyone having a similar issue, the problem here was with the version number, which contained a leading zero: 3.2.02.  Hopefully better error messages will implemented soon...